# Spring-ws : Cannot bind a prefix to the empty namespace name

Tags: bind, xml-namespaces, spring-ws, prefix

we are using spring-ws-core 2.1.1 to consume the webservice but sometimes we got "Cannot bind a prefix to the empty namespace name" issue

> 2018-05-04 14:54:15,254 INFO  [Thread-11118]
>   com.abc.wsconsumer.ilog.client.impl.IlogClient - ilog.action:
>   executeNBUnderwriting 2018-05-04 14:54:15,254 INFO  [Thread-11118]
>   com.abc.wsconsumer.ilog.client.impl.IlogClient - investigate log:
>   20170611 version 2018-05-04 14:54:15,254 INFO  [Thread-11118]
>   com.abc.wsconsumer.ilog.client.impl.IlogClient -
>   getWebServiceTemplate###########org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate@2e636311 2018-05-04 14:54:15,254 INFO  [Thread-11118]
>   com.abc.wsconsumer.ilog.client.impl.IlogClient -
>   request###########com.abc.wsconsumer.ilog.client.components.RuleDto@4f7079eb
>   2018-05-04 14:54:15,260 ERROR [Thread-11118]
>   com.abc.wsconsumer.ilog.client.impl.IlogClient - Cannot bind a prefix
>   to the empty namespace name

Could you please help advice how it comes and the solution to fix?
It's sporadic.. it's random happen.. not all time.

Thanks